# How to display the posts of the current user

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, loops, widget

I'm trying to create a widget to display a list of posts liked by the current user in Wordpress.

All I'm getting is all the posts liked by all users. How could I improve my code so I can somehow filter and show only the posts liked by the current user?

Thanks in advance

How my code looks like:

```
        global $wpdb;
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );

        echo $before_widget;

        $results = $wpdb->get_results(
            "SELECT wp_hearts_table.post_id, 
            wp_hearts_table.owner_id, 
            wp_posts.post_title          
            FROM wp_hearts_table 
            INNER JOIN wp_posts 
            ON wp_posts.ID = wp_hearts_table.post_id " ); 
     
        //Widget content output
        echo '<h4>My Heart It Posts &#10084;</h4>';
       
        if(!empty($instance['amount'])){
            //list of posts
            echo "<ul>";
                foreach($results as $result){ 
                    echo "<li>";
                    ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($result->post_id) ?>">
                    <?php echo $result->post_title ?>
                    </a>
                    <?php
                    echo "</li>";
                }
            echo "</ul>";
        }

        echo $after_widget;
    }
```

Comment: You get the `user_id` at the top of your code but you didn't use it to filter your query